# Trying to multi thread a network task in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, networking

I am having issues using another thread in Android for checking the availability of a web server.

I start a new thread to avoid:

```
NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

This is the log cat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(17753): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2370
E/AndroidRuntime(17753): Process: com.example.c3po, PID: 17753
E/AndroidRuntime(17753): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
E/AndroidRuntime(17753): at com.example.c3po.MainActivity$1SecondThread.run(MainActivity.java:72)
```

The code used in the second thread

```
class SecondThread extends Thread {

        public void run() {

            TextView pingResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.checkStatus); // to display result

            EditText userText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userData); // take in user url
            String result = userText.getText().toString();

            try {

                InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(result); // user input is result (a URL)
                boolean b = address.isReachable(3000); 
                String str = String.valueOf(b); // turning the value of the boolean into string
                pingResult.setText(str); // value displays as true or false - LINE 72

            }
            catch (UnknownHostException e) {pingResult.setText("WRONG");} // will fill with helpful message later
            catch (IOException e) {pingResult.setText("WRONG");}


        }
```

And the button to trigger the thread:

```
    Button sendPing = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pingButton);
    sendPing.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick (View activity_main) {

            SecondThread thread = new SecondThread();
            thread.start();

        }

    });
```

Line 72 is commented. I have tried googling the specific issue, but have got mixed results.

Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are updating ui from the background thread. You cannot do that. Ui needs to updated on the ui thread. Use `AsyncTask`.

You could use

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            pingResult.setText(str); 
                        }
                 });
```

Similarly for `pingResult.setText("WRONG");`

But better to use AsyncTask as it would be a easier. You could do your background computation in `doInBackground` return result ie String in this case and update ui in `onPostExecute`